# PHP & IMAP: EmailReplyParser not returning message

Tags: php, imap

I'm using the [EmailReplyParser by Will Durand](https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser) and the *getContent()* method doesn't appear to be returning anything.

```
// Code adapted from "Retrieve Your Gmail Emails Using PHP and IMAP" by David Walsh ( https://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap ).
// Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php
public function imap () {
    $array_messages = array();
    // Attempt a connection.
    $this->inbox = imap_open($this->array_parameters['hostname'], $this->array_parameters['username'], $this->array_parameters['password']) or die("I cannot connect: " . imap_last_error());
    // Grab the Messages.
    $emails = imap_search($this->inbox, 'ALL');
    if( is_array($emails) && ( count($emails) > 0 ) ):
        $user = $this->flexi_auth->get_user_identity();
        // Organise the Messages in chronological order.
        rsort($emails);
        foreach($emails as $email_number):
            $note_id = 0;
            if ( $user == $this->flexi_auth->get_user_identity() ):
                // Get the information specific to each Message.
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($this->inbox, $email_number, 0);
                $message = imap_fetchbody($this->inbox, $email_number, 2);
                // Get the meta data.
                $array_messages['seen'] = $overview[0]->seen;
                $array_messages['subject'] = $overview[0]->subject;
                $array_messages['from'] = $overview[0]->from;
                // Format the time.
                $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'D, d M Y H:i:s O', $overview[0]->date);
                $array_messages['date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                // Get the Message.
                $objMessage = (new EmailParser())->parse($message);
                $fragment = current($objMessage->getFragments());
                $array_messages['message'] = $fragment->getContent();
            endif;
            $note_id = $this->messages_model->add(
                    $array_messages['from'],
                    $array_messages['date'],
                    $array_messages['seen'],
                    $array_messages['message'],
                    $array_messages['subject']
            );
            if ( $note_id > 0 ):
                imap_delete($this->inbox, $email_number);
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    imap_close($this->inbox, CL_EXPUNGE);
    return true;
}
```

If I swap *$fragment->getContent()* for *quoted_printable_decode($message)*, everything works.

I'm not seeing any errors with EmailReplyParser in so far as referencing it (the installation via Composer went without a problem).